# Full-screen mode in Firefox on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, fullscreen

Does anyone know of a solid solution for adding a full-screen mode to Firefox (3.5) on OS X? I've come across a few possibilities involving either Javascript bookmarklets or outdated add-ons, but nothing that works very well.

Comment: Those bookmarklets and add-ons are your best bet. There is no way to have true fullscreen in Firefox on a Mac, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you go into the info.plist file for your FireFox application and add in an item for Application UI Presentation Mode you can automatically hide the dock and the menu bar whenever the application is active:

[image]

That way as soon as you launch it the menu and dock will disappear and you can just hit the zoom button to fill the entire screen.  Tabbing over to the other applications will bring back the dock and menubar as will mousing up to the top and bottom edges when firefox is in focus.

Comment: Great tip! Didn't work for me at first - I couldn't add it as a String. Instead I had to add "LSUIPresentationMode" (type Number) with a value of "4"

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it's not possible to maximize a firefox window completely on a mac. However, it is possible to maximize the window to fit in the whole screen. To do this just follow these steps:

1. Create a new bookmark by right clicking on the bookmark toolbar. If you don't see the bookmark toolbar just go to View > Toolbars > check Bookmark toolbar.
2. Give the bookmark a name like Fullscreen (something that you can remember) and then paste the code below in the Location box. Make sure you paste all the code in 1 line only though, or else it won't work.

   ```
   javascript:self.moveTo(0,0); 

   self.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
   ```

   [image]

3.Click OK, and then just click on the Fullscreen button to maximize Firefox.

Then once you click on the Fullscreen Button, Firefox should then take up all the space that OS X allows an application to take up, depending on the size and position of your dock. Sometimes, when I'm viewing pictures, I like to minimize the dock by pressing `Cmd + Option + D` and this will allow Firefox to take up more space.

Source: http://beyondteck.blogspot.com/2007/12/fullscreen-in-firefox-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: That isn't generally what is meant by full screen at all. It simply maximises the Window without hiding any bars or anything

Answer (score 1):

Real full screen mode in Firefox on Mac OS X is now in the nightly builds (Minefield). It works great. If I understand it correctly, the feature will be included in the upcoming 3.6 release.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help.
http://jeff.globl.org/projects/firefox/fullerscreen-1.0x.xpi
works for me in OSX 10.5.7 and Firefox 3.5.5

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3.6 allows this: Shift-Apple-F

Comment: "Does anyone know of a solid solution for adding a full-screen mode to Firefox (3.5) on OS X?" note the 3.5.

Comment: Or Shift-Command-F, for newer keyboards. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want full screen mode on most Mac apps you need to add it using a utility like mega zoom. Check version tracker to see if megazoomer is ready to be installed on whatever version of OS X you're running.

The menu bar takes up such a tiny amount of usable screen real estate that it really doesn't matter.

Link : http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/21275/megazoomer

Comment: It only works for Cocoa applications. I believe Firefox is Carbon

Answer (score 0):

Use Add-on : Full Fullscreen 3.3

Link :https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1568

Comment: Doesn't work very well on Mac OS X. Just fills the screen with the window and hides the toolbar. The menubar and dock remain visible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Firefox solution, but [Plainview](http://www.barbariangroup.com/software/plainview) is apparently the only full screen browser for OS X. It has lots of unique features that aren't in Firefox, such as a presentation mode, where preset websites can be switched between using the keyboard, and a kiosk mode. It can also be run as a chrome free HUD window.