# How to remove the Dock in Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard, dock

I don't want the dock that is at the bottom of the screen. I don't want to hide it but completely remove it. How can this be done? If not possible, why not?

Comment: What? Remove the dock?!?! Why would you want to do something like that? That's like disabling the taskbar on Windows!

Comment: @musicfreak - It's not perfect and scales horribly. http://www.asktog.com/columns/044top10docksucks.html this question sorely needs some cleaning up.

Comment: @musicfreak, hence why I use Emerge Desktop on windows; the taskbar is totally useless to me.

Comment: My comment was actually made tongue-in-cheek. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best bet is to leave it there so you won't mess with other services but shrink it to super small size using the following terminal command:

> defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 1

see below for example .. that's wicked small.

[image]

then pin it to one side with the following terminal command:

> defaults write com.apple.dock pinning -string start

then hide it.  It should be totally out of the way at that point unless you mouse all the way over in the extreme bottom left hand corner.

Comment: To assign a shortcut to the above, see [In Mac OS X 10.6, is there a way to disable the trigger that shows the dock when the mouse is at the edge of screen](http://superuser.com/questions/187367/in-mac-os-x-10-6-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-trigger-that-shows-the-dock-when/187396#187396)

Comment: Options for pinning it include `start`, `middle`, and `end`. Also you will need to restart the dock by using `killall Dock` (make sure Dock is capitalized). Tested and this answer works fine on Lion too. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can remove Dock.app, change its permissions, or disable the launchd plist that opens it:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Dock.plist
```

To revert the changes, replace `unload` with `load` or remove the entry in `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` manually.

It also disables Mission Control, full screen windows, the Notification Center sidebar, the application switcher, Launchpad, Dashboard, and it makes desktop backgrounds gray.

This would increase the delay before the Dock is shown to 2 seconds:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 2; killall Dock
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called: [Dock Disabler](http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/extras.html) ([Source](http://www.applematters.com/article/ditch-the-dock-and-other-visual-clutter/))

The Dock isn't perfect but disabling the Dock entirely will break certain features (eg. Expose in Tiger and Panther)

Comment: is it safe? if i install your source to mac, it wont make affect ot os. Because it's nt my mac. i am on job.

Comment: If its not your system, you shouldn't be making changes to core services or installing software that modifies the OS.  The vast majority of companies *really* don't like that.

Comment: Disabling the Dock also disables cycling through apps via command-tab. It did for me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in a comment, you just want a full screen app. In that case, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/16586/full-screen-mode-in-firefox-on-os-x/16674#16674) to do that.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "my application"? If it's a third-party application with a full screen mode, file a bug report with the developer. If you're developing your own application, use CGDisplayCapture. If you're trying to maximise everything, try using your Mac like Apple wants you to. It sounds obnoxious, but it'll be easier for you in the long run.

If, however, you really do want to bend the OS X UI to breaking point (not that far, admittedly), follow Bryan's advice. Better still, stick it in an AppleScript, along with code to reverse it, and stick it in the Script menu. Then just select that item to switch between normal and hidden-away-really-small-in-the-bottom-left mode. And don't forget to ask the developer for a full-screen mode!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot disable the dock. Even quitting the dock process results in it auto-magically restarting.

You cannot disable the dock because it is an integral part of OS X.

Why do you want to remove it? What benefit do you believe you'll get from removing it?

Comment: i want my application in full screen.
there should a button at the bottom to on/off dock.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically anything is possible I suppose, the Dock application is in /System/Library/CoreServices so for starters you could pull it out of there I suppose.

But I don't think Finder will like that, and you also will lose the Expose feature, and maybe Dashboard too.  I can't imagine why disabling/removing it would be preferable to simply hiding it.

Comment: hiding - it re-appear when i dont require.
so i need to close it.
I want full screen for my apps.

Comment: Because your mousing up to the edge of the screen and it's sliding back on the screen?  You could change the position and pin it to the top of the screen so its REALLY hidden

Comment: Actually in 10.5 you can't pin it to the top of the screen anymore

Comment: and i am using mac 10.5.7