# iTerm 2 window resizing

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, iterm2, resizing

My iTerm 2 window is up against the menubar at the top of the screen.

When I resize the window vertically from the top to the bottom, a small gap is always left. It never resizes down fully to the bottom.

I think this is because it is only resizing within whole terminal rows and columns.

Is there anyway to stop this behaviour, I can't bear to look at this much longer ;)

Answer (score 66):

I finally got the answer!

ref:
https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3375

Go to the following menu option:

Preferences - Advanced - Windows - Terminal Windows resize smoothly - Yes

Holding Control will temporarily disable snap-to-grid.

Answer (score 12):

Press "Control" while resizing will let you overcome the resizing limit. But this is still annoying because I have to manually resize after using BetterTouchTool's window snapping.

Comment: This was the perfect solution, I'm sure there's a reason it's not the default behavior but I wish it was.

Answer (score 5):

I was suffering the same annoyance until today.

Open `Preferences > Profiles > Text > Regular Font > Change Font` and play with the font Size and/or Vertical Character Spacing. Test your changes by making an adjustment, resizing iTerm, making another adjustment, and rinse/repeat until the window size lands where you want. On my MBPr, using the Monaco font, a Size of 10 and Vertical Spacing of ~1.25 did the trick.

Edit—Another possible solution:

For the **Default** profile, open `Window` and set `Settings for New Windows > Style` to either `Bottom of Screen` or `Top of Screen` and `Settings for New Windows > Columns` to `134`.

New iTerm window title bars will be hidden and iTerm will be flush to the menubar but it's not possible to resize or move the window without first dragging out the iTerm tab (mine are bottom alined so you can't see them in the screenshot) at which point the title bar reappears, taking us back to square one.

I was able to use a pre-made [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom) preset to move the window into place without the title bar present; that's how in the following screenshot I got iTerm without title bar positioned on the right:

[image: iTerm Flush]

Comment: Thanks, nice workaround, but I don't want to change the font size ;)

I just think I'm going to have to live with the gap :(

Comment: I edited in another possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the default height of new windows to something like 999 rows, they fill up the screen vertically. Also uncheck these settings:

- Appearance > Hide tab bar when there is only one tab
- General > Adjust window when changing font size

I always use iTerm in full screen. I have set Profiles > Window > Style to Fullscreen and unchecked General > Use Lion-style fullscreen windows (so there's no animations and ⌘H is not disabled). There is a bug where the menu bar is always shown in Resume'd custom full screen windows though.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these options worked. Setting the window height to 999 still leaves a gap and the other options don't seem to have any affect :( I would like to use iTerm fullscreen, but I have dual monitors and it makes the second monitor unusable by blanking it out.

Comment: I don't have two displays at the moment, but even if you don't use Lion-style full screen windows? There's also the 4 pixels taken up by the Dock. [Disabling the Dock](http://superuser.com/questions/18244/how-to-remove-the-dock-in-mac-os-x-leopard) isn't really practical, but you can change desktop backgrounds (or the bottom parts) to black.

Answer (score 0):

(iTerm2 Build 1.0.0.20131124@OS X Lion 10.7.5)

What I found out is that when I enable the toolbar I do not have any resizing issues (in addition I experience the same gap horizontally to the right of the window).
But as soon as I disable the toolbar (View -> Toggle Toolbar) I can resize the window horizontally and vertically to the maximum without any gaps at the bottom/right side of it.

Feels like a bug, not a feature. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a *good enough* solution using El Capitan, with iTerm2 Build 2.1.4.

I already use [spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) for window snapping so I typically position my terminal horizontally using spectacle's [keyboard shortcuts](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle#keyboard-shortcuts).

Then in iTerm2, I checked the box under `General > Window > Zoom button maximizes vertically only`.

From there clicking on the titlebar gets rid of the gaps above and below the iTerm window. I can also confirm that if you follow [Step 3](http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/22/5-simple-window-management-keyboard-shortcuts-to-improve-workflow-in-mac-os-x/) for creating a `Zoom` keyboard shortcut this will also do what you'd expect.

Hope this helps!